# Best way trim to finish shower to bath transition?

Tags: bathroom, shower, tile, trim, finishing

I'm about to start tiling the shower for the master bath, and I wanted to make sure we used the proper transitions from tile to the drywall.

I guess I have two questions.. is there anything I need to do with the current gaps between the shower board and dry wall before tiling for the flat wall and corner transitions? And then what kind of trim piece would be best for each?

The shower tiles are 12"x24," so I'm not sure about tiling around the corner there. Just want to make sure this is finished right. Thanks!

[image: Flat transition]

[image: Corner transition]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as those edges are supported from behind the wall, you don't need to do anything. You can fill the gaps in with the thinset when you actually do the tiling. Along the flat wall, think about installing some bull nose pieces on the drywall and butt them up against your shower tile. Along the corner wall, install  some outside corner tile down the corner with your shower tile butted up against one edge and bull nose tile butted up against the other edge on to the drywall. This could vary depending on the finishing edges of tile pieces you find at your tile stores.